# How to add text input in Jquery Mobile onclick?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The following code works fine without Jquery Mobile:

```
$('#addfield').click(function() {
    $('<input type="text" value="" />').appendTo('form');
});
```

However, if I start to use Jquery Mobile by adding this in the head tag:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>`

It doesn't work anymore. (it works on a desktop browser but not in a real mobile browser (i.e., Android default browser)

Do you know the Jquery Mobile equivalent of the code above?

Comment: what errors are you getting because that works http://jsfiddle.net/Hc3Zn/

Comment: @popnoodles it works on desktop but not in a real mobile browser (i.e., Android default browser)

Comment: works on my android phone too http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hc3Zn/show/

Comment: @popnoodles you are right. I should use `<button>`. I used `<input type="button" />` and that was the problem I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell jquerymobile to init the added code with:

```
$('input').textinput(); 
// or, in your case 
$('<input type="text" value="" />').appendTo('form').textinput();
```

Comment: This works in "beautifying" the form. I need this too. Thanks.

Comment: BTW how do you use `textinput()` if you have a bunch of other stuff to add? e.g., `$('<div>Name: <input type="text" />Email: <input type="text" /></div>').appendTo('#items');`

Comment: You can use the first line in the answer. You just need to select them all.